# Boundary for sprites in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have various sprites on my screen and they are chasing after their target. That all works fine.

My question is, is there a way to set a boundary? I do not want them to be able to move above 160 points on the screen?

Every example I see is always using box2d, is there a way to do it strictly with cocos2d?

```
- (void)addPlayers {
    winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    _officer = [[Officer alloc] initWithLayer:self];
    _officer.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 40);
    _officer.tag = 1;
    [_batchNode addChild:_officer];

    _shotCaller = [[ShotCaller alloc] initWithTeam:2 layer:self];
    //create spawn point
    _shotCaller.position = ccp(100, 100);
    [_batchNode addChild:_shotCaller];

    NSString *gunName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gun.png"];
    _gun = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:gunName];
    _gun.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.25);
    _gun.position = ccp(_shotCaller.contentSize.width/2, _shotCaller.contentSize.height/2 -   20);
    [_shotCaller addChild:_gun];
    [self moveRandom:_shotCaller];

    NSMutableArray *team1GameObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:_officer];
    NSMutableArray *team2GameObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:_shotCaller];
    _gameObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:team1GameObjects, team2GameObjects, nil];
}

for(CCSprite *myNode in _gameObjects)
{
    if (myNode.position.y == 160 ) {
        NSLog(@"1");
        [self checkCollision];
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error?
-[__NSArrayM position]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84597b0

all I want to do is have the sprite stop at 160 and that what the checkCollision method is for. just sets its position to 160.

Comment: Ehhh, whatever code is moving your sprites, make it so that it won't move past your boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want them to do when they get to their threshold?

You could just check them in an scheduled update method.

Somewhere in your init you can run

```
[self schedule:@selector(update:)];
```

This will call the update method every frame.

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
     for (CCSprite *s in self.arrayOfSpritesToCheck)
     {
           if(s.position.y > 160) {
                 //Do something
           }
     }
}
```

As for your updated question, you are running position on an `NSMutableArray`. Your gameObjects array is an array of arrays. When you do `for (CCNode *myNode in _gameObjects)` it  doesn't guarantee the objects coming out will be CCNode's and in fact in your case they are `NSMutableArray`'s.

Comment: I was doing that and it worked. The only issue I had was it also moved my background to what ever I set the sprites to do. So I guess the real question is, How could I do that and exclude the background, which is a sprite?

Comment: Don't loop through self.children. Loop through an array that you create of the sprites you want to be fixed

Comment: I know what you are telling me to do is 100% correct, but I am still getting an error. Im going to edit my question and put some code in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the setPosition method in your sprite (game object) class and limit the vertical position to never exceed 160.